# how to use and edittext input as an int for a switch

Tags: android, android-edittext, switch-statement

I want to use the users input from the edit text, covert it into an int and use it in my switch statment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button convert;
    Button erase;
    EditText display;
    ToggleButton switcher;
    int input;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


             pause.start();
    // Calls my variables
    InitializeVars();
}

// SLEEP 2 SECONDS HERE ...
Thread pause = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

};

// My variables
private void InitializeVars() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bConvert);
    erase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bErase);
    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDisplay);
    display.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    switcher = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbSwitch);

    switcher.setOnClickListener(this);
    convert.setOnClickListener(this);
    erase.setOnClickListener(this);

}

// My functions for anything that is clickable embedded with a switch
// statement
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.tbSwitch:
        if (switcher.isChecked()) {
            display.setText("Text1");
        } else {
            display.setText("Text2");
        }
        break;
    case R.id.bErase:
        display.getText().clear();
        break;
    case R.id.bConvert:
        input = Integer.getInteger(display.getText().toString());
        input = (input / 10);
        switch (input) {
            case input = 10:
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

So after the input this is what it looks like 
and when i try to use my input in my case(for the switch statment)  get "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing I'm noticing about that line is that you're trying to give `input`, which is an `int` an `Editable`. `display.getText()` returns an Editable object. I think what you actually want is

```
input = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().toString());
```

Since parseInt() will throw a **NumberFormatException**, you might want to implement a try/catch block to catch any input that isn't an integer. It will make your application more robust.

As for your thread. You don't call it anywhere. It's fine but wherever you need it, you must call `pause.start()` though it's really unnecessary. I agree with President Evil on that regard.

Comment: okay so I edited my code with those, but when I do my switch statment I get "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Comment: I firgured it out thanks!!!!
I had
   switch (input) {
    case input == 10: //wrong
     break;
    case 10://correct
     break;
   }

Comment: How would I add my try/catch to that? would i use pasreint() as my try and just make a method with that?

Comment: You would surround your parseInt() with a try block and have a catch block after that to handle the NumberFormatException error by either prompting the user to enter a valid number or whatever else.

Comment: so I would create a blank method for parseInt(). and do the code like
       `try{parseInt();
    
   }catch (NumberFormatException e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   }`

Like it works when I try it but a number will never apprea beacuse I set my edit text as numbers in the XML. So I guess would this be the proper code if some how the user entered anything other than a number

Comment: What do you mean by make a blank method for parseInt? You would use the line in my answer in the try block. So it would be something like `try{ input = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().toString()); }catch...etc.`

Answer (score 0):

`display.getText()` will return a String, not an int, which is what you've declared `input` as. You'll need to call `input = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().toString())` and handle any Exceptions that might throw (I don't remember off the top of my head).

Your `Thread` code is correct but will never be called. You'd be better off just calling `Thread.sleep(2000)` wherever you need it - it doesn't need to be wrapped in a `Thread` (but you do still need to catch the `InterruptedException`). However, if you want to keep it the way it is, you'll need to call `pause.start()`.

Comment: I think display.getText() actually returns an Editable, not a string. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29

Comment: i've tried that and it gives me "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)"

Comment: @Otra Ah, I should've checked that. I'll edit my answer for future reference.